# If the area of a sphere is $\frac{81\pi}{\sqrt{27}}$ what is it's radius?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been stuck in this textbook problem for so long now, basically if the radius is $R$ then:

$4\pi R^2 = \frac{81\pi}{\sqrt{27}}$

The textbook says the solution is one of these:

$a)\ \ \frac{3}{2}\sqrt3$

$b)\ \ \frac{3}{2}\sqrt[4]3$

$c)\ \ \frac{9}{2}$

$d)\ \ \frac{9}{4}\sqrt3$

The solution is suppose to be $b)$ but I have never been able to get that answer.

Comment: Also, welcome to Math.SE! If you can let us know what answers you've gotten, and how you've gotten them, we'll be better able (and more likely) to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $4\pi R^2 = \frac{81\pi}{\sqrt{27}}$ divide by $4\pi$ to get 
$$R^2=\frac{81}{4\sqrt{27}}=\frac{3^{4}}{2^2\cdot 3^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{3^{\frac{5}{2}}}{4}
$$
Then square root to get
$$R=\frac{3^{\frac{5}{4}}}{2}=\frac{3^{1+\frac{1}{4}}}{2}=\frac{3}{2}3^{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[4]{3}
$$

as required!

Comment: Thank you, but how did you get from $\frac{3^4}{2^2⋅3^\frac{3}{2}}$ to $\frac{3^\frac{5}{2}}{4}$?

Comment: No problem. In that expression, the $2^2$ becomes the $4$ and $\frac{3^4}{3^\frac{3}{2}}=3^{4-\frac{3}{2}}=3^\frac{5}{2}$.